# Gdiplus::Image::FromStream returns NULL

Tags: c++, image-processing, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+

I'm writing a function that load PNG picture from resource file to a `Gdiplus::Image` variable. Here is the funtion I wrote:

```cpp
bool CPngImage2::LoadImage(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCTSTR pszResourceName)
{
    ASSERT(m_pImage==NULL);
    if (m_pImage!=NULL) return false;

    HRSRC hResource=NULL;
    HGLOBAL hGlobal=NULL;
    IStream * pIStream=NULL;

    try
    {
        hResource = FindResource(hInstance, pszResourceName, TEXT("PNG"));
        if (hResource == NULL)
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"FindResource Error!\nError Code: %d", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        hGlobal=LoadResource(hInstance,hResource);
        if (hGlobal==NULL) 
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"LoadResource Error!\nError Code: %d", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        LPVOID pImageBuffer=LockResource(hGlobal);
        if (pImageBuffer == NULL)
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"LockResource Error!\nError Code: %d", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        DWORD dwImageSize=SizeofResource(hInstance,hResource);
        if (dwImageSize == 0)
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"SizeofResource Error!\nError Code: %d", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL,TRUE,&pIStream);
        if (pIStream==NULL)
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"CreateStreamOnHGlobal Error!\nError Code: %d", err);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        HRESULT ret = pIStream->Write(pImageBuffer,dwImageSize,NULL);
        if (ret != S_OK)
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"pIStream->Write Error!\nError Code: %d\nHRESULT return value: %d", err, ret);
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        m_pImage = Image::FromStream(pIStream);
        if ((m_pImage == NULL) || (m_pImage->GetLastStatus() != Gdiplus::Ok))
        {
            int err = GetLastError();
            CString errstr;
            errstr.Format(L"Image::FromStream Error!\nError Code: %d\nImage Status: %d", err, (m_pImage == NULL ? -1 : m_pImage->GetLastStatus()));
            MessageBox(NULL, errstr, NULL, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            throw 0;
        }

        if (pIStream!=NULL) pIStream->Release();

        if (hGlobal!=NULL)
        {
            UnlockResource(hGlobal);
            FreeResource(hGlobal);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        if (pIStream!=NULL) pIStream->Release();

        if (hGlobal!=NULL)
        {
            UnlockResource(hGlobal);
            FreeResource(hGlobal);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I use it to loadt picture,it pops a error report messagebox:

Image::FromStream Error!
Error Code: 0
Image Status: -1

And m_pImage's value is NULL.
I want to know what is causing this error and how can I fix it.

Enviroument Information:

System: Windows 10 Professional Workstation Version 21H1

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 (lastest version)

Comment: [CreateStreamOnHGloabal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-createstreamonhglobal) returns an `HRESULT` and doesn't set the thread's last error code. Indeed, all calls to `GetLastError` after a failed COM call are meaningless. See [Error Handling in COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/error-handling-in-com) for reference.

Comment: Also consider using [SHCreateMemStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) instead. The resource is already mapped into memory. Copying the contents into a new stream is wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the advice. But the error is caused by Gdiplus::Image::FromStream function, and using `SHCreateMemStream` insteaed of `CreateStreamOnHGloabal` does not help.

Comment: Maybe so, but that could well be the result of a previous call failing, which the code in question isn't observing. Still, if an implementation based on `SHCreateMemStream` fails in the same way, then it's likely that your source image is invalid. Make sure it's in one of the [supported file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nl-gdiplusheaders-image) and properly encoded.